# Java stream().map() for Two Java Objects

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
Class Person{
 private int id;
 private  String name;
 private String address;
 private int mobile;
  ----- Getter and Setter and constructor --
}

 // suppose this comes from front end for updation id and name
 Person person1 =new Person(1,"a");
 Person person2 =new Person(2,"b");
 List<Person> persons = new ArrayList(); 
 persons.add(person1);
 persons.add(person2);
 newPersons = persons.stream()
                .map(p-> new Person(p.getId(),p.getName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

repository.saveAll(newPersons);
```

I am using JPARepository. Above saveAll function update the existing name according to id but address and mobile becomes null. So basically First I want to get whole object using findById and pass the existing data, to be updated data in constructor ,create new list and pass to saveAll().

I want to initialize person constructor some values from list and same values from db as I want to update my list of person values in db.

I want something like this. How we can do this?

```
newPersons = persons.stream()
                    .map(p-> 
                      p1 -> findById(p.getId()) 
                      new Person(p.getId(),p.getName(),p1.getAddress(),p1.getMobile())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to save for example `[{1,"a","oldadd","oldmobile"},{2,"b","oldadd","oldmobile"}]`

Comment: This doesn't compile: `List<Person> persons = [{1,"a"},{2,"b"}];` What are you doing there?

Comment: It's unclear what you want your output to be. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Sweeper I have modified the question.